# Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER

Tags: puppet

First of all, I'm totally new to puppet.

I can't seem to get my puppetnode to accept a module.

I've been through the quickstart guide at puppetlabs: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/quick_start.html

I've installed the first module (motd) as described in the docs, and everything went fine.
Now I've tried with another module from puppetforge (torrancew::account)

> puppet module install torrancew-account

I've added the class 'acount' to the class listing using the Puppet Enterprise Console. It didn't autodetect the class but adding it manually seemed to work.

I've added the class to my node, and when editing its parameters, I see all the default values as expected.

If I try to test the module on the node

> puppet agent --test --noop --debug

I get the following error:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find class account for puppetnode1.tabulex on node puppetnode1.tabulex
>   Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
>   Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

---

What am I doing wrong

Do I need to do anything else for the module to work?
How do I define the username for the user (users) to be created?

I can find lots of info about how to do it with a shell and file editing, but now by using the Enterprise Console.

Comment: It seems that it's my understanding that's way off. Account is not a class but rather a definition: define account(........) Still no idea how to make it work though

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/torrancew/account) you just place this in a manifest (.pp).

```
account { 'sysadmin':
    home_dir => '/opt/sysadmin',
    groups   => [ 'sudo', 'users' ],
    ssh_key  => 'AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEArfQmMkvtWRnwas3DIti9qAuSFQXKcE0kdp5f42PP8l2kTytJPPWp5T/q8PXDQ2d2X5KplMCMDiUQkchqhmDp840jsqBQ9iZPejAjv3w2kITgScFNymAcErtzX52iw4lnUyjZzomCW8G3YthQMaRm2NkI4wcVcjzq+SKyTfzrBoH21RgZlfcx+/50AFRrarpYqel9W5DuLmmShHxD8clPS532Z/1X+1jCW2KikUhdo98lxYTIgFno05lwFOS9Ry89UyBarn1Ecp1zXpIBE7dMQif3UyLUTU9zCVIoZiJj4iO5lemSSV0v8GL97qclBUVJpaCpc4ebR7bhi0nQ28RcxQ==',
    comment   => 'SysAdmin user',
}
```

Comment: As far as I've understood it. If I add the above code to the manifest file. This code will be run on every node I want to use the account module on. I do not want that. I'd like to be able to define individual accounts based on which class the server belongs to. Furthermore I believe it can be done through the GUI, but I might (easily) be mistaken.

Comment: So you have to define those accounts somewhere.  Typically you would create a new module (i.e. `my_accounts` that would create the accounts).  Inside said module, if it was a "database" server, you could have conditional logic creating the various DBA accounts.

Comment: Additionally, the above example is an example.  Modify to suit your needs.